# Вопрос по папке public в Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Все кто пользуется Laravel знают что при установке проэкта нужно заходить в папку public.
Сдедовательно много кто ищет как решить эту проблемму, и я в том числе.

В интернете есть видео где "умельцы" вырезают файлы из папки

```
/public
```

вставляют их в корневую директорию.

Потом меняют 2 алиаса в файле

```
index.php
```

После такого подхода есть много проболем.
Первая: не работает asset{}, вроде как проблемму можно решить но на большом проэкте будет еще какой геморой если все пути нужно будет перезаписывать.
Вторая: получаешь легко доступ по ccылке к файлу /.env где хранится пароль от базы данных. Дальше я думаю можно не рассказывать что можно сделать.

Кто может подсказать как правильно настроить переадресацию c помощью .htaccess файлом например в Laravel.
Так чтобы все нормально работало и чтобы не было копии страницы по адресу domain.com/public.

Comment: Ну зачем тебе менять `public` папку? Хостинг?

Comment: Нет, просто хочу понять чтобы сделать сайт на локалке и все было красиво.
Сейчас у меня такая ситуация - я создал .htaccess  в корне из таким кодом ( нашел где то в интернетах

 <code>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</code>

Ну и у меня работает сайт когда ввожу просто адрес, без поддиректории /public

Но копия сайта работает тоже в папке public.

Comment: Ну так на локалке и настрой сервер так, чтобы он смотрел в `/public` директорию. В чем проблема? Если используешь OpenServer (OsPanel) - там все просто - Настройки -> Домены, выбрать "ручное управление" или "автопоиск + ручное управление" и добавить Имя домена (например `site.local`) и папку домена (выбрать в проводнике папку `/public` проекта)

Comment: Сейчас бы костыли свои придумывать. Не случайно структура сделана именно так. Всё, что ниже папки /public/, пользователю вообще показывать строго запрещено.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое Максим.
Так и сделал.
"Если используешь OpenServer (OsPanel) - там все просто - Настройки -> Домены, выбрать "ручное управление" или "автопоиск + ручное управление" и добавить Имя домена (например site.local) и папку домена (выбрать в проводнике папку /public проекта)"

Самый нормальный вариант.